# how to specify two conditions in a collect in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my system I have the notion of a cost. A cost belongs to one user and to one trip.
I am trying to extract all the costs that belong to a specific user and to a specific trip.

doing

```
  @trip.costs.collect {|cost| [cost.value, cost.exchange_id]}
```

will get me all the costs for a specific trip

and doing

```
current_user.costs.collect {|cost| [cost.value, cost.exchange_id]}
```

will get me all the costs for a specific user.

How do I combine both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

collecting costs attributes for a specific trip of a specific user:

```
current_user.costs.where(trip_id: @trip.id).collect { |c| [c.value, c.exchange_id] }
```